Excel: VBA script to concatenate text until the next cell that starts with a number?
In Excel I have the data as shown in columns A and B.
I would like to automatically populate the data shown in column C.



A
B
C - desired result




01/Feb/2024
Text 1
Text 1


01/Feb/2024
Text 2
Text 2, Text 3, Text 4, Text 5, Text 6


Text 3









Text 4
Text 5








Text 6




01/Feb/2024
Text 7
Text 7


01/Feb2024
Text 8
Text 8



I'm really struggling to write a VBA script to do this. Please can someone help?
I tried the following script:
Sub ConcatenateUntilNumber()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String
    
 
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    result = ""
    
    
    For i = 1 To lastRow
    
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
        
            If IsNumeric(Left(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, 1)) Then
            
                If result <> "" Then
                    ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = result 
                End If
                result = "" 
            Else
                
                If result = "" Then
                    result = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
                Else
                    result = result & ", " & ws.Cells(i, 1).Value & " " & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub

But this is the only result:



A
B
C - result




01/Feb/2024
Text 1



01/Feb/2024
Text 2



Text 3









Text 4
Text 5








Text 6




01/Feb/2024
Text 7
Text 3, Text 4 Text 5, Text 6


01/Feb/2024
Text 8





Are the dates in Col A actual date values, or text?

If you have access to MS365 then perhaps you can accomplish the desired output using the following formula as well:


• Formula used in cell C2
=LET(
     a, A2:B8,
     b, TAKE(a,,1),
     c, ISERR(--b),
     d, SCAN(0,1-c,LAMBDA(x,y,IF(y,x+1,x))),
     e, IF(1-c,MAP(d,LAMBDA(z, TEXTJOIN(", ",1,IF(ISERR(--a)*(z=d),a,"")))),""),
     e)



This worked perfectly! Thanks very much.

@JS glad to know it worked for you!

Now done. I have to manipulate the data about 5000 rows at a time, but that's no problem for me.

@JS you can convert the range into structured references aka tables that should help.

Try this out:
Sub Compile()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, lr As Long
    Dim c As Range, cDest As Range, sep As String, v
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet9")
    'last row in A or B
    lr = Application.Max(ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row, _
                         ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    Debug.Print lr
    For Each c In ws.Range("A1:B" & lr).Cells
        'date in col A ?
        If c.Column = 1 And c.Value Like "##/???/####" Then
            Set cDest = c.Offset(0, 2) 'set the destination cell
            sep = ""                   'reset the separator
        Else
            v = c.Value
            If Len(v) > 0 And Not cDest Is Nothing Then
                cDest.Value = cDest.Value & sep & v
                sep = ", " 'populate the separator after first value
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub


I tried this. The script ran but nothing happened in column C, or anywhere else.

A small tailoring would need for your code
There is a restriction that the first item in Column A cannot be a Text rather a date.
Sub ConcatenateUntilNumber()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String
    
 
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3")
    
    
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    
    result = ""
    
    
    For i = 1 To lastRow
    
        If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value <> "" Then
            If IsNumeric(Left(ws.Cells(i, 1).Value, 1)) Then
               counter = 0
               ws.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
                
               
            Else
                counter = counter + 1
                ws.Cells(i - counter, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i - counter, 3).Value & ", " & ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
                If ws.Cells(i, 2) <> "" Then
                 ws.Cells(i - counter, 3).Value = ws.Cells(i - counter, 3).Value & ", " & ws.Cells(i, 2).Value
                End If
            End If
        Else
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next i
    
End Sub



I tried this but the script would not run, due to an unrecognised command in the second instance of the row starting "ws.Cells(i.."

If you use Option Explicit then declare Dim counter As Long for the program.
